# installing postgres in azure ubuntu virtual machine using powershell

Tags: postgresql, powershell, azure, ubuntu, azure-virtual-machine

I am able to create ubuntu virtual machines using powershell script in azure. 
But i would like to know how to install postgresql database into newly created ubuntu virtual machine of azure, and also other softwares if needed.

I need a help in doing so in powershell. any guidelines or suggestions on it.

Comment: Will you be logging in to the VM , or you want to do it as from outside?

Comment: use custom script extension for that

Comment: I want to do it as from outside , i mean as soon as creating virtual machine. It should be with powershell script only. Planning like automating the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you could not install  postgresql outside VM with PowerShell. You need write a bash script to install postgresql like this [example:install_postgresql.sh](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/postgresql-on-ubuntu/install_postgresql.sh).

You could use [Azure Custom Extension](https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/tree/master/CustomScript) to execute this script.

You can deploy CustomScript Extension by running:

```
$RGName = '<resource-group-name>'
$VmName = '<vm-name>'
$Location = '<location>'

$ExtensionName = 'CustomScriptForLinux'
$Publisher = 'Microsoft.OSTCExtensions'
$Version = '<version>'

$PublicConf = '{
    "fileUris": ["<url>"],
    "commandToExecute": "<command>"
}'
$PrivateConf = '{
    "storageAccountName": "<storage-account-name>",
    "storageAccountKey": "<storage-account-key>"
}'

Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $RGName -VMName $VmName -Location $Location `
  -Name $ExtensionName -Publisher $Publisher `
  -ExtensionType $ExtensionName -TypeHandlerVersion $Version `
  -Settingstring $PublicConf -ProtectedSettingString $PrivateConf
```

You also could use this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/postgresql-on-ubuntu) to achieve this.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name shuitest -ResourceGroupName shui -TemplateFile "D:\azuredeploy.json"
```

Comment: @ManVin It is easy for you to deploy postgresql when you create VM.

Comment: am getting an error when following above custom script usage as per your code guidelines. i have slightly modified code and getting an 
error status code: 127

Comment: Now finally it got worked as per your suggestions. Thanks alot. Saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

@Walter - MSFT

I tried by not executing Set-AzureVMExtension , it has thrown error after some time as below:

Set-AzureRmVMExtension : Long running operation failed with status 'Failed'.
ErrorCode: VMExtensionProvisioningError
ErrorMessage: VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'customscript'. Error message: "Enable failed: failed to execute command: command terminated with exit status=127".
StartTime: 6/29/2017 10:09:39 PM
EndTime: 6/29/2017 10:10:03 PM
OperationID: 9d615221-e656-4367-a5e8-57441a323a93
Status: Failed
At E:\Projects_EDrive\Azure\PowerShellScripts\CentOSVM.ps1:95 char:1
+ Set-AzureRmVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VMName $VMName -Lo ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmVMExtension], ComputeCloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.SetAzureVMExtensionCommand

---

I manually connected to VM and tried to install basic packages called apt, apt-get , erlang(rabbitMQ message broker dependency) using below commands:

sudo yum install apt
sudo yum install apt-get
sudo yum install erlang

it says no packages found, looks like nothing available on created VM.